# Access individual data in a collection passing to Notification method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-notification

I have queried a list of users based on a filter to send out notifications and i want to use this collection method to send out the notification.

[Collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notification-facade)

As in the documentation i pass the users collection to the notification and my post data

```php
Notification::send($users, new PostAlert($post));
```

I believe, this collection method is firing notifications in a loop. One-by-one.If it is, how do i access a user's details inside the notification ? i can only access `$post` details for now

```php
Notification::send($users, new PostAlert($users, $post));
```

Doing the above passes the collection and i cannot access a single user detail inside the notification.

I know that i can set the firing on a loop, but i believe it is not the cleanest way

```php
foreach($users as $user) 
{
   Notification::send(new PostAlert($user, $post));
}
```

It would be very helpful if you could help me how would i access a single model passing from collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy, Try it,

You will find a variable called `$notifiable`

```
// PostAlert
...
// toMail() or toArray()
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    dd($notifiable,"the user laravel is sending to.");
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
...
```

Happy Codding.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought of `dd`ing the `$notifiable`.

Comment: You are very welcome. `dd` is a really helpful function do not forget to use it.